# Can't remote into a spawned EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am not able to remote desktop into a T2.micro instance that I spawned from the AWS Java API.  Here is what I did:

1. Created an instance using the Amazon console
2. Successfully remoted into it
3. Created an AMI of the instance
4. Wrote a Java program to runInstance using the same security group, availability zone, subnet, and keyname as the original
5. Ran the program and saw it start successfully
6. Tried to connect and got the message:  "Password is not
   available. This instance was launched from a custom AMI, or the
   default password has changed. A password cannot be retrieved for
   this instance. If you have forgotten your password, you can reset it
   using the Amazon EC2 configuration service"

Am I missing something?  Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is more server config or something. Try superuser or serverfault.

Comment: It most likely IS a programming question.  The issue is probably AWS API related.  Step 4 lists the setters used, and the problem could be that either a setter was missed or additional functions need calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say *Tried to connect and got the message "Password is not available"*, do you mean you connected with RDP or do you mean that you were in the AWS console, you right-clicked the EC2 instance and you selected "Get Windows Password"?

Unless you explicitly did something to prevent it (see below), I would expect the administrator password of the new instance to be the same as the old instance.

If you want a new administrator password for the new instance, then you need to use the EC2ConfigService on the original instance and configure it so that a new password is generated on next boot. Then you can stop the instance and create an AMI from it. When a new instance is launched from the AMI, it should then allow you to retrieve a new password.

Comment: I got the "Password is not available" from the AWS console when trying to connect.  Your response was a huge help in that I realized I could bypass the whole "Get Password" and just remoted in and use the password of the original instance.  That worked!  Thanks!